# Usage of Mysql IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am storing in a column a list of category id that are separated by commas:

Like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.. and so on, just their IDs.

Then I am doing a query to get all the rows that have the category with the ID 2,3 and it works when the list of packages has few items.

This is the query and the table:

```
mysql> select *  from packages where category_id IN (2,3);
```

Any solution to get complete list of packages that contains ctegory id either 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer to you question:

`select * from packages where category_id LIKE "2" or category_id LIKE "3";`

However, you better denormalize the data.

Answer (score 0):

**Bad idea for de-normalize**

You should normalize the data

One possible solution for this

```
mysql> create table the_in ( expr varchar(255));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into the_in values('1,2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table some_table ( id int(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into some_table values (1), (2), (3), (4);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from some_table 
where find_in_set(id, (select expr from the_in));
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`find_in_set` - **beware on the performance**